# Why can't a reference and a pointer be used together?

Tags: c++

I am a history of C development and have recently been studying C++. I have been studying what '&' means and have been quite confused about why it can't be used in conjunction with a pointer.

So far, I am interpreting any variable declared by a '&' in the parameter as always changing the value implicity by going `*variable = ...` essentially always derefencing the variable and changing the variable. Similiar to if a pointer was being passed and the value change is always by derefencing the value.

So it got me thinking, why is the C++ code below not acceptable?

**Why can I not pass a pointer, to a function that accepts a parameter by using '&'. The value being used in the function would be equivalent of going 
 '*r = ...' for everything assignment done by r**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void square(int& r) {
    r = r * r;
}

void x() {
    int org = 5;

    int* orgp = &org;

    square(orgp);

    std::cout << org;
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    x();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Highly related: [passing pointers to function that takes a reference?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3316447) Somewhat related: [dereferencing a pointer when passing by reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/11347111)

Comment: As you note dereferencing a pointer gives you a reference. `*r = ...`. But there is no automatic conversion from a pointer to a reference and they are fundamentally two different types. So if you pass a pointer to a function that takes a reference then you will get an error as there is no way for the compiler to convert the pointer into a reference to make it a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Because a pointer is a pointer and a reference is a reference; you can however get a reference given a pointer by using the unary `*` operator (dereferencing):

```
void x() {
    int org = 5;

    int* orgp = &org;

    square(*orgp);   // ok

    std::cout << org;
}
```

Symmetrically, you can obtain a pointer given a reference using unary `&` (note: you cannot get the address of a reference, what you will get is the address of the **referenced** value).

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to an `int` and a reference of an `int` are different types. The pointer is an address in memory, the reference is an alias; it is another name for an `int` variable. Besides the language abstraction, the data behind a reference to an `int` is an `int`. A pointer and an `int` are (usually) different size objects and they always have different semantics. They cannot be interchanged.

You can pass by reference the value pointed by the pointer variable (i.e. `*orgp`):

```
void x() {
    int org = 5;

    int* orgp = &org;

    square(*orgp);

    std::cout << org;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

> A reference is just another name for some variable. [[axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac)]

At least, this is a good way to look at the matter.

Technically, there actually *are* cases where a reference really isn't implemented at all:

```
int a = 7;
int& b = a;
```

Most likely the compiler will use `a` directly wherever b is used instead of ever creating a true reference.

For function parameters (unless, possibly, if the function is inlined) or if capturing return values under the hoods the reference will most likely hold the address of the variable it references, just like a pointer does. Once being compiled, I doubt pretty much you could distinguish the two overloads

```
int f(int& n) { return  n; }
int f(int* p) { return *p; }
```

one from another other than by the mangled name.

Technically... From user's point of view, it still is easier just to stay with the cited comment, even if the variable referenced is located outside the function, let the reference be implemented explicitly or not. You just get away with easiest.

About correct usage – well, there *are* [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55017890/1312382) already, so this one is just contributing some background...